# Give a example of a matrix equation in $\mathbb{F}_p$ field

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $A\in{M_p(\mathbb{F}_p)}$,  $B\in{M_p(\mathbb{F}_p)}$, satisfy:
$$ AB-BA=I_p.$$

Over the field of characteristic zero, this equality is impossible because $\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(I)=p$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Hint. For $p=3$
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\quad
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$